# css - transition for hover:after

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS code:

```
.li2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
    color: white;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
.li2:hover {
    position: relative;
}
.li2:hover:after {
    content: url("images/small_show.png"); 
    display: block;
    background-size: 19px 19px;
    width: 19;
    height:19;
    position: absolute;
    left: 34px;     
    top: -30px; 
    transition:0.5s;    

}
```

...And I want some transition for appear image under text but my code doesn't work. What I have bad? 
Thank for every answer.

Comment: What do you want to change? What should the animation consist of?

Comment: I want appear image under image when I put mouse on text and animation can be some transition

Comment: "Some transition" doesn't mean anything. You can't tell CSS you want "some transition"! You will have to be specific! Do you want the picture to grow from size 0x0? Fade in? Drop in from the top of the screen? What?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what transition you are looking for, but here is a start. You need to define the properties for `::after` before the `:hover`. Like so:

```css
.li2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
    color: red;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 70px;
}
.li2:hover {
    position: relative;
}
.li2::after {
    content: url("http://placebabies.com/200/300"); 
    display: block;
    background-size: 19px 19px;
    width: 19;
    height:19;
    position: absolute;
    left: 34px;     
    top: -30px; 
    opacity: 0;
    transition:0.5s;    
}
.li2:hover::after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li class="li2">List Item</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Well, I was waiting for the OP to clarify their question before posting the very same solution (except that mine had a 19x19 picture).

Answer (score 1):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/128/

**HTML**

```
<p class="li2">lorem ipsum dolor</p>
```

**CSS**

```
.li2 {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display:inline;
    position:relative;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial;
    color: black;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-left: 70px;
    position: relative;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}

.li2:after {
    content: url("http://placehold.it/350x150"); 
    display: block;
    background-size: 19px 19px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;  
    top: 20px;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
    opacity: 0;
}

.li2:hover::after {
   opacity: 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead

```
-moz-transition:0.5s all linear;
-webkit-transition:0.5s all linear;
-o-transition:0.5s all linear;
transition:0.5s all linear;
```